# Transform text to uppercase in Scratch

Tags: function, for-loop, case-sensitive, uppercase, mit-scratch

My niece is trying to do a school assignment with scratch and asked for some help. Her assignment is to create a script that takes in a password mixed with numbers and lowercase letters and she has to change the letters from lowercase to uppercase. I have never used scratch before.. I tried my best but I'm not sure where I am making the mistake. I set evengroup as the variable containing what would be the password. I created a new function which I based off of something I found online and incorporated that in an iteration of the password on the left. Any ideas?

[image: Scratch Code]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[image: Answer picture]

It had the problem when the string contained an number it doesn't stop, so I fixed it.

and see the [discussion on scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/173757/?page=1#post-1671081)

Answer (score 1):

I have defined two custom blocks:

**position**

Set a variable `position$` to the position of `character` in `text`. 0 means that given character was not found in given text. We'll use that block to check each character of the password against the set of lowercase letters.

**uppercase**

Pass each character of the password to the `position` block. If `position$` is not 0 then current character was a lowercase letter and find the corresponding character in the set of uppercase letters. Otherwise keep the current character. The `uppercase$` variable accumulates the result of either of these checks.

```
define position [character] [text]
    set [position$ v] to []
    set [pos_i v] to [0]
    repeat until <<(position$) > [0]> or <(pos_i) > (length of (text))>>
        if <(letter (pos_i) of (text)) = (character)> then
            set [position$ v] to (pos_i)
        end
        change [pos_i v] by [1]
    end
    
define uppercase [text]
    set [uppercase$ v] to []
    set [upp_i v] to [1]
    repeat (length of (text))
        position (letter (upp_i) of (text)) [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]
        if <(position$) > [0]> then
            set [uppercase$ v] to (join (uppercase$) (letter (position$) of [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])
        else
            set [uppercase$ v] to (join (uppercase$) (letter (upp_i) of (text))
        end
        change [upp_i v] by [1]
    end
    
when green flag clicked
ask [Enter your password] and wait
uppercase (answer)
say (uppercase$)
```

[image]

---

If you want to see how this looks in Scratch3, there is a snippet below:

```html
<script src="https://github.com/scratchblocks/scratchblocks/releases/download/v3.5.2/scratchblocks-v3.5.2-min.js"></script>
<pre class="blocks">
define position [character] [text]
    set [position$ v] to []
    set [pos_i v] to [0]
    repeat until <<(position$) > [0]> or <(pos_i) > (length of (text))>>
        if <(letter (pos_i) of (text)) = (character)> then
            set [position$ v] to (pos_i)
        end
        change [pos_i v] by [1]
    end
    
define uppercase [text]
    set [uppercase$ v] to []
    set [upp_i v] to [1]
    repeat (length of (text))
        position (letter (upp_i) of (text)) [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]
        if <(position$) > [0]> then
            set [uppercase$ v] to (join (uppercase$) (letter (position$) of [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ])
        else
            set [uppercase$ v] to (join (uppercase$) (letter (upp_i) of (text))
        end
        change [upp_i v] by [1]
    end
    
when green flag clicked
ask [Enter your password] and wait
uppercase (answer)
say (uppercase$)
</pre>
<script>
scratchblocks.renderMatching('pre.blocks', {style: 'scratch3'});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

To make text uppercase, you might just want this:

[image: iUS.svg]